# ¿Como hacer un comando call en discord.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Comando call que cuando ejecutes el comando envie un MD a una persona random y esta responda en el MD

he intentando esto pero no funciona

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("g.call")) {
    if (!message.channel.type === "dm") return message.reply("> **Usa este comando en MD**");
    var usuario = message.guild.members.random();
    usuario.send(message.content.replace('g.call ', '')
}
});
```